# MATLAB lab worker allocated memory

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, shared-memory

I was wondering when we are running `spmd` blocks and create individual lab workers, then how much is the memory allocated to each of them them?
 I have an 8 core machine and I used 8 lab workers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you launch workers using the `matlabpool` command in Parallel Computing Toolbox, each worker process starts the same - they're essentially an ordinary MATLAB process but with no desktop visible. They consume memory as and when you create arrays on them. For example, in the following case, each worker uses the same amount of memory to store `x`:

```
spmd
    x = zeros(1000);
end
```

But in the following case, each worker consumes a different amount of memory to store their copy of `x`:

```
spmd
    x = zeros(100 * labindex);
end
```

Comment: @Eric - Thanks. But do you know what is the end-limit of memory allocated? They consume memory as and when I create the arrays. But if I create extremely large arrays, and allocate them to each lab worker, where is the limit? I tried running a code with 8 lab workers and allocated each lab worker 5 huge large size arrays, and the internal RAM got filled and the program stalled. However the same arrays when distributed among 4 lab workers, could easily process them. I have 16GB internal ram, and when I create lab workers each worker is allocated some amount of it. I was wondering how much.